# Cin operation error in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I create easy program which take name for user and counts a letters.
I debug this program in Visual Studio 2015, but i have errors..
[Error list image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3aPE.jpg)

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "iostream"
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    using namespace std;


    int main()
    {
        string name;
        int name_number = name.length();
        cout << "Your name: ";
        cin >> name;
        cout << name << endl;
        cout << "Your name have: " << name_number << "letter";

        return 0;

}
```

I debug this same program in Code blocks and everything is ok, so i dont know where is problem..

Comment: name.length() is pointless before doing cin >> name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `#include <string>`, as it includes the missing overload operator.

Comment: Absolutely no problem :)